# check if a tree is a mirror

Tags: python, tree

Hello I have a code to check if a tree is a [mirror tree](https://csegeek.com/csegeek/view/tutorials/algorithms/trees/tree_part9.php). However it doesn't pass all the test cases on leetcode.

I checked with other sources online but can't seem to figure out the bug in my code.

```
# Definition for a binary tree node.
# class TreeNode:
#     def __init__(self, x):
#         self.val = x
#         self.left = None
#         self.right = None

class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if root is None:
            return True

        if root.left and root.right:
            return self.is_symmetric(root.left,root.right) 

    def is_symmetric(self, left, right):

        if (left == None and right == None):
            return True
        if right is None or left is None:
            return False
        if left.val == right.val:
            return True
        return self.is_symmetric(left.left,right.right) and self.is_symmetric(left.right,right.left)
```

Thank you!

Comment: What's the reason for the `if root.left and root.right` check in `isSymmetric`? (Also bear in mind that, when this check fails, the function implicitly returns `None`.)

Comment: Also, you need to define to what a mirror tree is. It's a not widely understood term but something that's defined by your problem.

Comment: https://leetcode.com/problems/symmetric-tree/description/

Answer (score 2):

When the condition that checks `root.left and root.right` is `False`, your `isSymmetric` function implicitly returns `None`. It should instead continue to check if one of `root.left` or `root.right` is not `None`, in which case it should return `False`; otherwise both `root.left` and `root.right` are `None`, and it should return `True`. Also, in the `is_symmetric` function, just because `left.val == right.val` it doesn't mean that the left subtree is symmetric to the right subtree, since there could be more children under them. It should simply return `False` when `left.val != right.val`:

```
class TreeNode:
    def __init__(self, x):
        self.val = x
        self.left = None
        self.right = None

class Solution:
    def isSymmetric(self, root):
        """
        :type root: TreeNode
        :rtype: bool
        """
        if root is None:
            return True
        if root.left and root.right:
            return self.is_symmetric(root.left,root.right)
        if root.left or root.right:
            return False
        return True

    def is_symmetric(self, left, right):

        if left is None and right is None:
            return True
        if right is None or left is None or left.val != right.val:
            return False
        return self.is_symmetric(left.left, right.right) and self.is_symmetric(left.right, right.left)
```

Answer (score -1):

Another option to check if the tree is a mirror tree is to find the paths to each node, and then check that all the paths are reversed:

```
class Tree:
  def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    self.__dict__ = {i:kwargs.get(i) for i in ['value', 'left', 'right']}
  @staticmethod
  def is_reversed(a, b):
     return True if not a and not b else all(int(c) == (not int(d)) for c, d in zip(a, b))
  def get_paths(self, path = ''):
    yield [self.value, path]
    yield from getattr(self.right, 'get_paths', lambda _:[])(path+'1')
    yield from getattr(self.left, 'get_paths', lambda _:[])(path+'0')

t = Tree(value=31, left=Tree(value=16, left=Tree(value=7), right=Tree(value=24, right=Tree(value=29), left=Tree(value=19))), right=Tree(value=45))
t1 = Tree(value=31, right=Tree(value=16, right=Tree(value=7), left=Tree(value=24, right=Tree(value=19), left=Tree(value=29))), left=Tree(value=45))
"""
        31     |      31
      /    \   |     /  \
    16      45 |   45   16
   /  \        |        / \
  7   24       |       24  7
     /  \      |      /  \
    19   29    |     29  19

"""
_paths1 = dict(list(t.get_paths()))
_paths2 = dict(list(t1.get_paths()))
print(all(Tree.is_reversed(_paths1[i], _paths2[i]) for i in _paths1))
```

Output:

```
True
```